# how to obfucate dependant .jar in Proguard?

Tags: java, android, proguard

I have a Jar library called BizLogic.jar and I am referring to it on my UI project. So when I obfuscate, I want to obfuscate BizLogic.jar first and then UI without breaking any references between them?

Is this possible with Proguard ? If not, Any other product that can support this ?

Thanks

Comment: check out the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820261/obfuscating-jar-files-with-other-jar-files-embedded

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most robust solution would be to process both jars at the same time, but to keep the output in separate jars:

```
-injars  UI.jar
-outjars UI_processed.jar
-injars  BizLogic.jar
-outjars BizLogic_out.jar
```

or with an output directory

```
-injars  UI.jar
-injars  BizLogic.jar
-outjars out
```

The UI code and the business code will then be consistent.

Alternatively, you can apply incremental obfuscation:

1) First process BizLogic.jar with these additional options:

```
-printmapping BizJar.map
-dontoptimize
-useuniqueclassmembernames
```

2) Then process UI.jar with this additional option:

```
-applymapping BizJar.map
```

Incremental obfuscation is more complex and sometimes tricky to get right.

All this and more is explained in the [ProGuard manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html).